# How to computer integral with Time dependency?

Tags: integration, python

I would like to compute the integral of discrete signal segment Y (Y=[y1,y2,...y50])  with X to be the corresponding time instants as in the following:

```
x=['2018-01-24T13:41:25.057000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.069000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.077000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.090000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.097000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.111000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.117000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.130000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.138000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.150000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.158000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.170000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.178000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.199000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.200000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.211000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.218000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.231000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.238000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.250000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.258000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.269000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.278000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.290000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.298000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.311000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.317000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.331000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.338000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.350000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.358000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.370000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.378000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.390000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.398000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.411000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.418000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.430000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.437000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.450000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.469000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.469000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.479000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.493000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.502000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.510000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.517000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.530000000'
 '2018-01-24T13:41:25.537000000' '2018-01-24T13:41:25.550000000']
```

Please, note that the distance between two points is not regular but it may change. 
My question is: Can I abstract the above time by considering the integral over X where I define X=[0,1,2,...49] or I need to consider the above times in a different way?

Many Thanks, Best Regards, carlo

Comment: One way to do this is the trapezoidal rule without assuming uniform trapezoid widths. It's quick-and-dirty, but it can give you a reasonable answer in some cases.

Comment: @Adrian Keister: Many Thanks. Yes, but How should I give the X input? Which format?

Comment: You'd have to give the $x$ input to do non-uniform trapezoid widths. Your formula would be $$A\approx \frac12\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\left[(y_j+y_{j+1})\Delta x_{j}\right].$$ You might be able to vectorize this in numpy or pandas.

Comment: @Adrian Keister: Yes, but I am trying to understand what are the xj concretely? Please, could you provide an example based on my X?

Comment: $\Delta x_j$ in the formula I just gave is equal to $x_{j+1}-x_j$, where $x_j$ is the $j$-th component of your $x$ array.

Comment: even if it is time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76109/discussion-between-carlo-allocca-and-adrian-keister).